# How can I convert a Docker image into a (vagrant) VirtualBox box?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, docker, packer

I've been looking at Packer.io, and would love to use it to provision/prepare the vagrant (VirtualBox) boxes used by our developers.

I know I could build the boxes with VirtualBox using the VirtualBox Packer builder, but find the layer stacking of Docker to provide a much faster development process of the boxes.

How do I produce the image with a Dockerfile and then export it as a Vagrant box?

Comment: This question deserves its extremely good up-vote ratio to the top answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Find the size of the docker image from `docker images`

```
REPOSITORY   TAG    IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
mybuntu   1.01   7c142857o35   2 weeks ago         1.94 GB
```

Run a container based on the image `docker run mybuntu:1.01`

Create a QEMU image from the container, 
Also, use the size of the image in the first command (`seek=IMAGE_SIZE`). 
And, for the `docker export` command retrieve the appropriate container id from `docker ps -a`

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=mybuntu.img bs=1 count=0 seek=2G
mkfs.ext2 -F mybuntu.img
sudo mount -o loop mybuntu.img /mnt
docker export <CONTAINER-ID> | sudo tar x -C /mnt
sudo umount /mnt
```

Use `qemu-utils` to convert to vmdk

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-utils
qemu-img convert -f raw -O vmdk mybuntu.img mybuntu.vmdk
```

More info on formats that are available for conversion can be found [here](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html). 
Now you can import the vmdk file in virtualbox

Comment: How would you do this under OSX?

Comment: This looks very scriptable... I'm going to try and let you know.

Answer (score 8):

Provided that your target is VirtualBox, it could be probably better if you use Vagrant for the whole process.

Vagrant ships with a [docker provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/docker.html) that could automatically install docker on the vm and build a `Dockerfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.build_image "/vagrant/app"
  end
end
```

Once your image is built, you can produce a vagrant box using the `vagrant package` command.

Comment: Yes, I'm very aware of this and the point of this question was to NOT use Packer's vagrant Builder, which is exactly what you're proposing.

Answer (score 1):

This is the route I'm going to try:

- docker export to get a tar ball,
- then create a VMDK using the qemu-* tools and steps as outlined here: https://superuser.com/a/482127/59809

This will allow me to setup/provision the machine using Docker, and then run it in Virtualbox controlled via vagrant.

Comment: Turned out that Docker version 0.10.0, build dc9c28f together with Ubuntu 12.10 is really unstable - it has frozen one of my servers multiple times: it has caused kernel panics. I've paused this attempt for now, but in theory there's no reason why this approach shouldn't work.